# Email configuration ProjectOpen

Tags: email, project-open

Email configuration in ProjectOpen is kind of a hazzel,

I used to configure my Linux Server to forward Emails to an appropriate Relay

I tested the functionality via the termail command:

```
echo "Message" | mail -s subject -r sender@abc.com receiver.abc.com
```

Unfortunately Project Open is still not able to send Emails.

The /var/log/mail.log says:

```
 A6FD4345661: to=<bounce-37074-3043FD5CD79FB795D3E26192C966ABF25806739A-21457@AS02>, relay=smtp.outlook.office365.com[132.245.74.114]:25, delay=10, delays=0.01/0/4.9/5.4, dsn=5.7.60, status=bounced (host smtp.outlook.office365.com[132.245.74.114] said: 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Well, that smtp relay denies the request. That is not an issue with project open, but the smtp relay and your permission within that.

Comment: The problem is that the FROM field is not populated even though I filled out the administrator and many other email fields with the correct sender. As a result of the empty from field the email is rejected (fake sender)

Comment: Ah, and you don't think that is viable information that belongs into the question? How should we know that? And how shall we help without you posting that configuration and other details? We cannot _guess_ these things...

Answer (score 1):

As arkasha wrote in a comment above: It seems that in your case the denial is due to your service provider rejecting email from an "untrusted" server, and not due to an issue in `project-open`. Please see the following two articles on how to deal with such a situation:

- http://www.project-open.com/en/configure-external-smtp-server
- https://sourceforge.net/p/project-open/discussion/295937/thread/9ab4720b/